# highcharts horizontal line data size

Tags: highcharts

How do I make a button to add a horizontal line with 3 points? 
1. Height
2. Beginning
3. The end
As in the example below.
Thank you very much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAYvx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class to add the line. For example:

```
document.getElementById('addLine').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var height = document.getElementById('height').value,
    start = document.getElementById('start').value,
    end = document.getElementById('end').value,

    xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
    x1 = xAxis.toPixels(start),
    x2 = xAxis.toPixels(end),
    y = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(height);

  chart.renderer.path(['M', x1, y, 'L', x2, y])
    .attr({
      'stroke-width': 5,
      stroke: 'red',
      zIndex: 4
    })
    .add();
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4782/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I have a problem:
I have new data added to the graph every second. Because of this, my schedule changes.
When I use your example, the line follows the movement of the graph and must be in its coordinates. How can this be resolved ?

Comment: Hi, You need to reposition the line in the `redraw` event. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4787/

Comment: You really helped me!
Thank you very much! 
Good luck in life! 
I'll thank you personally sometime, and I'll have more questions about hightchart.
Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, the same for you! Just create a question with `highcharts` tag and I will try to help you :)

Comment: Please give me an example: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4787
How do I add text over a line?

Comment: Use `renderer.text` method in the similar way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4794/

Comment: Thank you very much!
Do not tell me how to assign an index to the line to delete the line on the button ?

Comment: @18 - Trader 18 plus - The lines are in an array, so they already have an index.